# How to fix hex UTF-8 bytes characters (in an latin1_swedish_ci table)

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I've got a latin1_swedish_ci databases with UTF-8 bytes characters in it, which are displayed as %C5%A1, %C4%8D,...

I already convert database and tables from latin1 to utf8, but i still need to fix UTF-8 bytes characters.

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

MySQL default character set:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%'

character_set_client    utf8mb4 
character_set_connection    utf8mb4 
character_set_database  utf8mb4 
character_set_filesystem    binary  
character_set_results   utf8mb4 
character_set_server    latin1  
character_set_system    utf8    
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

I tried MySQL function without success:

```
convert(cast(convert(name using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
```

I really need help here! Thank you.

Comment: Are they only displayed like this, or are they actually stored with these escape sequences (ie. containing actual percent signs)?

Comment: Hi lenz, they actual contain percent (example of word: pisarni%C5%A1ka), and the actual word should be (pisarniska) - LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON.

Comment: Or perhaps `pisarniška`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using PHP?  Is there a call to `urlencode()`?  Don't.  Use that function only for building url strings.

Let's double check what you have *in the table*.  Do `SELECT HEX(...) ...` -- `pisarniška` should become (spaces added for clarity):

```
70697361726E69 C5A1 6B61   if correctly stored as utf8mb4 (or utf8)
70697361726E69 254335 254131 6B61   if urlencoded first
```

Comment: Hi Rick James, thanks for your help. The output of SELECT HEX(...) ... -- pisarniška is v 254335 254131 6B61

Comment: Therefore, `urlencode()` (or something) was called _before_ inserting into the table.  You need to follow the trail of what was done to the text before the MySQL `INSERT`.  If you are using PHP, grep for "urlencode".  If not, then it may be some other function that turned `š` into `%C5%A1`.  The problem is that only URL processing in a browser knows how to reverse the transformation.